# How to convert files to ADAM format?

Tags: sam, vcf, adam

I would like to convert BAM and VCF files to [ADAM](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam) format.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These transformations are quite simple with the `adam-submit` script packaged with ADAM.

**Transformation of BAM files**

```
adam-submit -- transformAlignments sample.bam sample.alignments.adam
```

**Transformation of VCF files**

```
adam-submit -- transformVariants sample.vcf.gz sample.variants.adam
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the package? It seems like it is [this repository](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam) but I'm not sure.